# What is the difference of training a caffe network using command line and python wrapper?

Tags: python, deep-learning, caffe

I used a custom dice loss layer in my caffe network for binary image segmentation. Everything works fine when I trained it using caffe command line:

```
$ caffe train -solver solver.prototxt
```

It did converge properly. But when I tried to train the same network using python wrapper:

```
solver = caffe.get_solver('solver.prototxt')
solver.solve()
```

I got an error:

> File "dice_loss_layer.py", line 42, in forward
>
> ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (32,160,128)
>   into shape (32,1,160,128)

Actually line 42 in dice loss is an empty line and the line above and below it are comment lines. If I replace the dice loss layer with a regular softmax layer, the error disappeared. But since dice worked well with the command line, I couldn't find anything wrong in the loss layer itself.

The only difference I notice between the dice loss layer and the softmax layer is the number of output fed to dice is 1 while to softmax is 2. I don't really know where to look at to solve the problem. Could anyone give me some directions?

Comment: check file paths, `$PYTHONPATH` make sure you are working with the right copy of `dice_loss_layer.py`. Are you sure both training procedures uses the same `solver.prototxt`?

Comment: Thank you for the reply! These are very good points. I checked both the solver and the dice loss layer. Actually I used the absolute path to the solver in both training procedures. To make the question clearer, I removed those paths from the above question. For the loss layer, if I add some 'print's, they did generate some additional output. So I believe I am working with the right copy of the loss layer.

Comment: I used hdf5 as input data. According to '\caffe\matlab\hdf5creation\demo.m', the hdf5 image data has dimension of W*H*C*N. But I am not sure of the dimension of the hdf5 mask label image. I used W*H*N and got the above result. And if I use W*H*1*N, the error disappeared, but the algorithm didn't converge any more...