# What is the meaning of 'self.diff' in 'forward' of a custom python loss layer for Caffe training?

Tags: python, caffe, pycaffe

I try to use a custom python loss layer. When I checked several examples online, such as:

[Euclidean loss layer](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/pycaffe/layers/pyloss.py), [Dice loss layer](https://github.com/yihui-he/caffe-dice-loss-layer/blob/master/perClassLoss.py),

I notice a variable 'self.diff' is always assigned in 'forward'. Especially for the Dice loss layer,

`self.diff[...] = bottom[1].data`

I wonder if there is any reason that this variable has to be introduced in `forward` or I can just use `bottom[1].data` to access ground truth label?

In addition, what is the point of `top[0].reshape(1)` in `reshape`, since by definition in `forward`, the loss output is a scalar itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the **diff** attribute of the layer for overall consistency and data communication protocol; it's available other places in the class, and anywhere the loss layer object appears.  **bottom** is a local parameter, and is not available elsewhere in the same form.

In general, the code is expandable for a variety of applications and more complex computations; the reshaping is part of this, ensuring that the returned value is scalar, even if someone expands the inputs to work with vectors or matrices.

Comment: I got it! Thanks so much for your reply! Would you mind taking a look at another question and giving me some suggestions: [Another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42791280/what-is-the-difference-of-training-a-caffe-network-using-command-line-and-python) ?

Comment: First, begging for cross-question help isn't really appropriate.  I do appreciate the invitation, though, and went over to take a look.  I'm afraid that this is beyond my ken; I'm not using the Python wrapper at all, nor do I work with inner layers of a topology.  Sorry I can't be of more help.

Comment: I mentioned the other question because I read a lot of your answers and found them helpful. I am sorry if you think that is not appropriate... Thanks anyway!

Comment: No great problem; just letting you know for your future citizenship in Stack Overflow.  I'm glad you're finding me helpful; I still have a lot to learn, myself.